# Angular4 http.post .NET Core MVC bind failure

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, angular, asp.net-core-mvc

Tried a lot of solutions to pass an object from Angular4 service to c# controller. Although I do have the object received in service, does not bind to c# controller and so, I receive **null**.

**Angular service:**

```
getShedule(payload: any) {
    this._http.post("Shedule/GetSchedule", payload)
        .map(res => res.json()).subscribe((x) => {
            console.log("callback succes");
        });
}
```

**C# controller:**

```
[HttpPost]
public void GetSchedule(object priceScheduleObject)
{ 
    //logic here
}
```

Any help is welcome.

Comment: Did you try it with an actual typed parameter instead of using "Object" on your controller? You most likely have a class called "PriceSchedule", try using that instead of "object"

Comment: Yes, I did it through PriceScheduleDTO  class as well, but although controller hits, values are still null.

Comment: What does your `payload` object look like? Have you verified that it isn't null?

Comment: Well, here is the structure: ` public class PriceScheduleDTO
    {
        public int Price { get; set; }
        public int Deposit { get; set; }
        public string Plan { get; set; }
    }`

Comment: Is that structure similar to the structure of "payload"? Are you sure payload is not null or empty? Can you post your HTTP Request details? EDIT: Try using Fiddler to capture the HTTP POST request

Comment: "payload" has the same naming to DTO and I do get it inside service(console.log). Http post details at the code above. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change your C# controller to

```
[HttpPost]
public void GetSchedule([FromBody] JObject priceScheduleObject)
{ /
```

The `[FromBody]` annotations let the ASP.NET Core Binding logic look into the body of the message (and not posted form fields).
If your do not want to interact with the JObject representing the JSON data you can bind the data to a model like

```
public class PriceSchedule {
   public string Name {get; set;} // just an example, propert names depend on your json
   ...
}

[HttpPost]
public void GetSchedule([FromBody] PriceSchedule priceScheduleObject)
{ /
```

Comment: I tried this solution and I got "Unsupported Media Type" - not even controller been hit. Is there something that has to be manipulated inside the service?

Comment: Please check the request in the development tools of your browser if they are sent as content type application/json and if the json in the request body is well formatted. If the content cannot be parsed by the registered serializers (JSON is as far as I know registered as default, for XML you have to do additional configuration) ASP.NET Core quits processing without hitting your controller.